# How to add an event on SVG click with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, meteor, svg

I have a SVG and I want to add an event listener on it.
My structure is the following one:

```
<template name="dataGraph">
  <div style="height: 100%;" class="right_col" role="main">
    <div id="logoObject">
      <object id="svg_compose" type="image/svg+xml" data="output.svg">Your browser does not support SVGs</object>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and in my JavaScript I did:

```
Template.dataGraph.onCreated(function dataGraphOnCreated() {
});

Template.dataGraph.onRendered(function dataGraphOnRendered() {
  $(document).on('click','svg',function(){
        alert('You clicked me svg');
  });

  $(document).on('click','#svg_compose',function(){
        alert('You clicked me svg_compose');
  });

  $(document).on('click','#logoObject',function(){
        alert('You clicked me logoObject');
  });
});

Template.dataGraph.events({
  'click #svg_compose': function(e){
    console.log("we are in the svg element");
  }
});
```

and the only listener who works is the one of `#logoObject`

[image]

My goal is to print the content of `<text>` when we click on the element.

Could you help me to get that because I'm trying and trying and trying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I learned that we can't use events with `<object>` so I used https://github.com/madebyshape/svg-convert